# How to connect to MongoDb with Hapi.js?

Tags: mongodb, hapi.js

Does anyone know how to connect to **MongoDb** while using the **Hapi.js** framework?

I have only managed to find one example (https://github.com/Marsup/hapi-mongodb), but this requires using a plugin and has no comments in the code!

Does anyone know of a simpler way?

Comment: Can you explain simpler?

Comment: Well in the example in the link, every time you write a handler function you will have to define `var db = request.server.plugins['hapi-mongodb'].db;` and `var ObjectID = request.server.plugins['hapi-mongodb'].ObjectID;`. That will become cumbersome over time. What I intend by simpler, is having a single connection instance outside of any handler functions. Like `var db = mongoose.connection()`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Blog post on user authentication with passport and Mongoose](http://emptymind.me/user-authentication-with-hapi-passport-and-mongoose/)

Also be aware that Hapi's model is based off of plugins so read and re-read the docs on building your own.

Answer (score 3):

The following (using mongoose) works pretty well for me:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 3000 });

var dbUrl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb';
var dbOtions = {
    db: { native_parser: true },
    server: { poolSize: 5 }
};

server.register([ /* plugins */], function (err) {
    if (err) {
        throw err; // something bad happened loading the plugins
    }

    // ... Register the routes

    server.start(function () {
        mongoose.connect(dbUrl, dbOtions, function(err) {
            if (err) server.log('error', err);
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

I use a hapi plugin that I wrote that connects to mongo, handles errors to log and adds bluebird promises.

```js
'use strict';

var bluebird = require('bluebird');
var mongoose = bluebird.promisifyAll(require('mongoose'));

exports.register = function(plugin, options, next) {

  mongoose.connect(options.mongo.uri, options.mongo.options, function (e) {
    if (e) {
      plugin.log(['error', 'database', 'mongodb'], 'Unable to connect to MongoDB: ' + e.message);
      process.exit();
    }

    mongoose.connection.once('open', function () {
      plugin.log(['info', 'database', 'mongodb'], 'Connected to MongoDB @ ' +  options.mongo.uri);
    });

    mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
      plugin.log(['info', 'database', 'mongodb'], 'Connected to MongoDB @ ' +  options.mongo.uri);
    });

    mongoose.connection.on('error', function (e) {
      plugin.log(['error', 'database', 'mongodb'], 'MongoDB ' + e.message);
    });

    mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {
      plugin.log(['warn', 'database', 'mongodb'], 'MongoDB was disconnected');
    });
  });

  return next();
};

exports.register.attributes = {
  name: 'mongoose',
  version: '1.0.0'
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Visit http://cronj.com/blog/hapi-mongoose

Complete sample project which can help you Repo Link https://github.com/gauravgupta90/Hapi-Mongoose-Angular

Config.js

```
module.exports = {
    server: {
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        port: 8000
    },
    database: {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 27017,
        db: 'DatabaseName',
        username: '',
        password: ''
    }
};
```

Server.js

```
var Hapi = require('hapi'),
Routes = require('./routes'),
config = require('./config'),
Db = require('./database');
var server = Hapi.createServer(config.server.host, config.server.port, {
    cors: true
});
server.route(Routes.endpoints);
server.start(function() {
    console.log('Server started ', server.info.uri);
});
```

Database.js

```
var Mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    config = require('./config');
Mongoose.connect('mongodb://' + config.database.host + '/' + config.database.db);
var db = Mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error'));
db.once('open', function callback() {
    console.log("Connection with database succeeded.");
});
exports.Mongoose = Mongoose;
exports.db = db;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
const Hapi = require("hapi");
const Mongoose = require("mongoose");

const server = new Hapi.Server({ "host": "localhost", "port": 3000 });

Mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb', { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err) => {
    if (!err) { console.log('MongoDB Connection Succeeded.') }
    else { console.log(`Error in DB connection : ${err}`)}
});
```